# Navigation Component: jump to dynamic root destination and clear backstack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

When using Jetpack Navigation, we can use `popUpTo` and `popInclusive` to clear the stack. But how do I clear the stack when I don't know what destination to `popUpto`?

#### Example

Say I have 3 main destinations that should have a clear stack when we arrive at them. And each main destination has its own flow of screens (which can be accessed directly with a deeplink).

Assuming the navigation flows downwards here:

```
Start app:
 - Main Dest 1 (nav to dest 2)
     - Dest 2 (nav to dest 3)
         - Dest 3 (nav to main dest 2)
            --clear--
 - (with clear stack)
   Main Dest 2 (nav to dest 4)
     - Dest 4 (nav to main dest 3)
         --clear-->
 - (with clear stack)
   Main Dest 3
 - Back button should close the app here
```

Since the navigation is very dynamic, I cannot guarantee the root destination. Even though I could, for example, pop up to "Main Dest 2", I cannot know that it's on the stack since I might have gone directly to "dest 4" from a URL.

I there a way of knowing which destination is the lowest so I can pop up to it and clear the stack?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no easy and beautiful way to get what you're trying to achieve.
There are a few possible solutions though.

---

#### Use some sort of a base fragment

You could have a base-destination which is always at the bottom of your stack, let's call it `baseDest`.
In your actions which need to clear the stack you could then always use

```
<action
    android:id="..."
    app:destination="@id/mainDestX"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/baseDest"
    app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
```

This will always keep your baseDest at the bottom of your stack allowing you to always popUpTo it.
To achieve your behaviour on a backpress in one of your main destinations you could either:

1. Override the `onBackPressed`-method in all your main dests to close the app. (Could be easily done if all your main destionations extend from the same class)
2. When your baseDest fragment is loaded because of an backpress close the app programmatically.

---

#### Rethink your app navigation

Maybe you should rethink how the navigation in your app works.
Rather than having some sort of possibly-cyclic graph structure it's easier to deal with tree-like navigation structures (which are also also more intuitively understood by users). Of course this is not always an option, but you should keep this in mind and consider restructuring your navigation.

---

#### Find a solution programmatically

Manually implement all your actions and navigations and use the methods provided in [NavController](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavController.html) to manually remove all entries in your stack before navigating to one of your main destinations.
One possible approch here to do this is to retrieve your nav controller by using the [findNavController](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/fragment/package-summary#findnavcontroller) method in your fragment.
I have not tested any of the following methods, but you could try to:

1. Execute `yourNavController.getGraph().clear()` followed by a `yourNavController.navigate(yourDest)`
2. At the beginning of your application before any fragment is loaded use `saved = yourNavController.saveState()` and on navigation to one of your mainDestinations use `yourNavController.restoreState(saved)`, again followed by a `yourNavController.navigate(yourDest)`
3. Create a new [NavGraph](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavGraph) and use `yourNavController.setGraph(createdGraph)`

Comment: Oh, don't get me started on this app navigation. It's completely out of my control - and I have told the people responsible for it about the many issues with the current one.

Comment: I have thought about this main dest approach, but it caused some issues. I can try to revisit it, maybe try a bit harder.

Comment: Anyways, do you mind extending a bit further on the _"manually remove all entries in your stack"_.

Comment: in earlier stages there was a clearTask attribute (or similar) in the navigation jetpack library, which was then marked as deprecated and later removed, so I doubt there will be an easier way, at least not by only using xml tags of you aren't able to restructure the navigation

Comment: When I have the time, I'll see if I can give this main dest option one more try. Maybe mess with the nagivation listener too, so the user doesn't see what they're not supposed to. Well, thanks for now. If you think of anything else, please, let me know.

Comment: I edited by answer to provide more information for my last point.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any official solution to the problem, but here's an approach that works for me:

```
private val mBackStackField by lazy {
  val field = NavController::class.java.getDeclaredField("mBackStack")
  field.isAccessible = true
  field
}

fun popToRoot(navController: NavController) {
  val arrayDeque = mBackStackField.get(navController) as java.util.ArrayDeque<NavBackStackEntry>
  val graph = arrayDeque.first.destination as NavGraph
  val rootDestinationId = graph.startDestination

  val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
    .setPopUpTo(rootDestinationId, false)
    .build()

  navController.navigate(rootDestinationId, null, navOptions)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a destination change listener in root or base fragment and listen for navigation changes.

```
NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    // react on change or 
    //you can check destination.id or destination.label and act based on tha
)}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this helps? What could be done inside the listener to accomplish the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The root of your graph is always on the back stack, so you can always `popUpTo` that destination.

So just make sure your root `<navigation>` element has an `android:id` associated with it:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@+id/main_dest_1">
    <!-- The rest of your graph -->
</navigation>
```

Then whenever you want to pop the entire graph, just `popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"`.

Of course, as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), you should **not** be popping the whole stack off when you go to Main Dest 2, Main Dest 3, etc. as it is extremely important from a UX perspective that users know when the back button will exit the app - that start destination is exactly that sign post for users to know when that'll happen and prevents accidental closure of the app when users expect to return to the first screen before exiting your app.

Comment: Can you write complete code for poping up to root ?

Comment: As per my answer, "you should not be popping the whole stack"

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have a use case where I use the bottom navigation controller to manage multiple backstacks. In our app, if a new user signs in, we need to clear these stacks so that the new user doesn't pick up where the previous user left off, seeing their data. So, is it possible to pop all backstacks when using a BottomNavigationView alongside Navigation?

Comment: Google should not be deciding how one should architect his/her code. What if the app uses a dynamic start destination graph? This is so absurd and this kind of headache is probably why people avoid the navigation lib

Comment: @Robin - you certainly can have a dynamic start destination, such as one based on a user preference. That is [specifically covered in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/programmatic#modify_inflated). If you're trying to change your start destination afterwards though, there's a better approach for anything you are trying to do with that. If you have a specific question you've posted where you've struggled with how to represent that, please include a link here.